# Install a specific version (vulnerable version) of apache2

Tags: apt, 20.04, software-installation, apache2

I am trying to install a vulnerable version of apache2 (version 2.4.49 to be exact) but when I run `sudo apt-get install apache2=2.4.49` it says the version is not found, although it definitely exists.

OS information:
VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"

ID=ubuntu

ID_LIKE=debian

PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; does it exist for your *unstated* release as we cannot check not knowing your OS & release.

Comment: fixed that, sorry

Comment: See https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+changelog. There are builds for 2.4.48 and 2.4.51. No 2.4.49. No 2.4.50. Please elaborate on what leads you to believe that a package for 2.4.49 exists and that the changelog is wrong.

Comment: If you need 2.4.49 specifically, you will need to use a Docker container. [This image here](https://hub.docker.com/layers/Httpd/library/httpd/2.4.49-alpine/images/sha256-84c4ce2c1a6863504160658e353e0179b87472912ee121b419e6c64343e5b334?context=explore) will give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu repositories contain only the newest versions available for your release of Ubuntu.

For older versions, you must download the deb from launchpad.net. Of course, this means you may also need to manually download any required dependency packages, too.

For the specific package `apache2`, look at the complete list of packages versions available for manual download at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2